# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{ak+b}; a>0,b>0$

Tags: calculus, limits, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function, beta-function

> Calculate
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{ak+b}, \qquad \tag{$a>0,b>0$}$$

My working:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{ak+b}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\int_0^1x^{ak+b-1}dx \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1\left(x^{b-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(x^a)^k\right)dx \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1x^{b-1}(1-x^a)^ndx \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1a \int_0^1x^{\frac{b-a}{a}}(1-x)^ndx \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1a B\left(\frac ba,n+1\right) \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1a\frac{\Gamma (\frac ba)}{(n+1)^\frac ba} \\
&=0\end{align}$$